# Printing possible substring in set of 3 and matching with dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing, substring

**I want to print possible substring in set of 3 and assign dictionary values  if pattern matches with dictionary.keys() and store them into new dictionary**

```
input:
dict1={'000': 0, '001': 0, '010': 0, '011': 0, '100': 1, '101': 0, '110': 1, '111': 0}
str1=['010110100']

output:
sub_string= [010,101,011...]
new dict= {'010':0, '101':0, '011':0, '110':1......}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
[str1[0][i:i+3] for i in range(len(str1[0])-2) if str1[0][i:i+3] in dict1]
{str1[0][i:i+3] : dict1.get(str1[0][i:i+3]) for i in range(len(str1[0])-2) if str1[0][i:i+3] in dict1}

# ['010', '101', '011', '110', '101', '010', '100']
# {'010': 0, '101': 0, '011': 0, '110': 1, '100': 1}
```

Comment: I already tried that it will give me ['010', '011', '100', '101', '110'], what I exactly want is [010,101,011,110,101,010,100]

Comment: @code_flipper i edit answer. is this your answer?

Comment: @code_flipper. welcome . if this your answer. please read this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
dict1={'000': 0, '001': 0, '010': 0, '011': 0, '100': 1, '101': 0, '110': 1, '111': 0}
str1= '010110100'

sub_string = []
d = {}

for i in range(len(str1)-2):
    temp = str1[i:i+3]
    sub_string.append(temp)
    d[temp] = dict1.get(temp)


print(sub_string)
print(d)
```

```
['010', '101', '011', '110', '101', '010', '100']
{'010': 0, '101': 0, '011': 0, '110': 1, '100': 1}
```